# jquery mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Iam just trying to create a product catalog with description hidden. it needs to show when the user hover on it. How to get this work?

```
<script>
    $("div.template_showcase").hover(function(){
          $("div.app_details").css('margin-top','-154px';); 
    },function(){

          $("div.app_details").css('margin-top','-8px';);
        }); 
</script>


<div class="template_showcase">
            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/templates/review.png" />
            <div class="app_details">
            <span class="paratitle">Review</span>
            <span class="para">
            Turn your jumbo in to a review site
            </span>
            <span class="addbutton">Add to Jumbo</span>
            </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra semi colons inside the css attribute assignment which is probably why your code is broken. You might find it easier just to use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). Although often useful negative margins are not supposed to be used.

```
<script>
    $("div.template_showcase").hover(function(){
          $("div.app_details").show(); 
        },function(){    
          $("div.app_details").hide();
        }); 
</script>
```